# jQuery Ajax Post in development Get in production

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a huge annoyance that I can't figure out . 
My Rails app issues a jQuery post request that works great in development , but turns into a Get in production . 
The assets seem to precompile correctly , I can actually beautify the production js code and find the exact ajax code (the same code I have in development..)

```
//my js
$(document).on("click", ".create-candidate-submit", function (e, data) {
urlToPost = DOMAIN_NAME + "stories/" + e.currentTarget.id + "/" + "candidates/";
console.log("urlToPost", urlToPost);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urlToPost,
    data: {"candidate": {
        "text": $("#createNewCandidate").val(),
        "story_id": e.currentTarget.id
    }
    },
    dataType: "script",
    success: function (res) {
        console.log("success called..", res);
        //  eval(res);
    }
});
```

});

```
   //erb
  <%= form_for [@story,@candidate],remote: true, html: {:role=>"form"} do |f|%>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="createNewCandidate">create story</label>
            <%=f.text_field :text,{:class=>"form-control",:id=>"createNewCandidate",:size=>30}%>
            <%=f.hidden_field :story_id%>
            <%=f.hidden_field :user_id %>
            <div class="btn btn-primary create-candidate-submit" id="<%=@story.id%>">שלח</div>

          </div>
      <%end%>

 applicaiton.js.erb
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require twitter/bootstrap
 //= require turbolinks
 //= require css_settings.js.erb
 //= require_tree .
```

Something is going wrong on production and I can't for my life of me figure it out .. please help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try $.post instead of $.ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Should have read jQuery docs more carefully (this has nothing to do with Rails)

"script": Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true. Note: **This will turn POSTs into GETs for remote-domain requests**.

I'm sure this is what is causing me the problem.